# Como puedo crear una ventana en **"Latino"**

Tags: interfaz-gráfica, ventana, latino

Quisiera saber como hacer una pequeña ventana en "Latino" ( Latino es un lenguaje de programación )
Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Y te fijaste en la documentacion? esta pregunta tiene una respuesta que es si o no... buscaste algo al respecto?

Comment: Busque y Busque, pero no encontre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamento informarte que actualmente (al momento de escribir esta respuesta), Latino no dispone de librerías gráficas en las cuales el usuario pudiera crear algo así como una ventana de programa. Las librerías gráficas de latino ya tienen años con su desarrollo paralizado.

Lo que sí podrías hacer es, ir al repo de la organización de Latino, y empezar a usar Latino para desarrollo web ya que sí se dispone de librerías como MySQL para Latino, Web-Sockets y HTTPsServer (Beta), las cuales sí te permitirán desarrollar una aplicación escrita en Latino al menos para la web.

Comment: Gracias por responderme y muchas gracias por la información, no estaba enterado